# Plotnine: How remove the ggplot:(xxx) type annoying text output when plotting a graph

Tags: python, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, plotnine

- Running jupyter notebook (python)
- Plotting using Python **Plotnine** library
- I plot and below the output graphic is annoying "ggplot2: (number)" output
- Normally you would put a `;` at the end of your notebook cell, but it **doesn't** seem to supress the annoying output text when i use Plotnine (but it does obviously work for matplotlib, etc)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8):

The point is in calling **draw()** method with **semicolon** at the end.

Fully working example:

```
import pandas
from plotnine import *
from random import randint

# 100 random numbers
random_numbers = [randint(1, 100) for p in range(0, 100)]

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': random_numbers})

# Draw plot
(
    ggplot(df, aes(x='number')) + 
    geom_histogram(bins=20, na_rm=True) +
    ggtitle('Histogram of random numbers') +
    theme_light()
).draw();
```

Comment: WORKS perfectly !  Much appreciated.  I looked forever trying to find a way around having that `<ggplot: (8762473532957)>` pop up at the end of the output.  Doesn't follow the standard matplotlib convention of just putting a `;` at the end of your command, like you pointed out, need to have the `.draw();' at the end...

Comment: WORKS perfectly !  Much appreciated.  I looked forever trying to find a way around having that `<ggplot: (8762473532957)>` pop up at the end of the output.   
Doesn't follow the standard matplotlib convention of just putting a `;` at the end, like you pointed out, you need to have the `.draw();' at the end... I swear everywhere i have seen plotnine output it doesn't have that .draw(); command, and so you see like on kaggle kernels where that text output isn't supressed.  THANK YOU.

Comment: Any matplotlib figure that is created in a cell is printed to the output when the cell run. Also the result of the last command in a cell is printed to the output. In plain matplotlib, you create a figure, plot stuff on it and when the cell is run that figure will be printed, no matter were in the cell it was created.

Comment: For plotnine, a figure is only created when the `draw()` method is called. When the `ggplot` object is the last in the cell, it gets printed `repr` style and it has to be a string. Before that string is returned, the `draw()` method is called, hence a figure.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work well in a loop. E.g. printing a loop with a text block, followed by a plot.draw(); will output all the text blocks first, and then all the plots.

Answer (score 1):

The `draw();` method didnt't work for me.

However, it did the trick:

`warnings.filterwarnings( "ignore", module = "plotnine\..*" )`